# Getting Serenity error 'Detached event' while trying to enter text feild values

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd

I am getting 'Detached event'error while trying to enter a text field value.

Error:
" net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: The following error occurred: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03', java.version: '11.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.80, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.140"

Updated the chrome driver  version to  77.0.3865.40

Can some one please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the Developer tools somehow? try without doing that. Please check if dev tools are getting opened during execution.

Comment: Nothing much to do https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing

Comment: I am not able to disable the bookmark tab too. it says the feature is enforced by the administrator

Comment: http://www.virusclean.org/guides/2029-remove-this-setting-is-enforced-by-your-administrator-from-chrome-guide-guides.html

Comment: https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-this-setting-is-enforced-by-your-administrator-virus/